# pl/sql, case, dmbs_output.put_line

Tags: oracle, plsql

simple question why I can't use dbms_output in that query:

```
declare
zmienna number(5);
polowa_zmiennej number(5);

begin
zmienna:=10;

polowa_zmiennej:=case zmienna
when 10 then 5
when 20 then 10
when 30 then 15
else 0
end;
dbms_output.out_line('bjbjbj');
end;
```

the error looks like that:
Error report -

> ORA-06550: linia 14, kolumna 13:
>   PLS-00302: component 'OUT_LINE' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: linia 14, kolumna 1:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Comment: It's `put_line` not `out_line`

Comment: oh no! shameful mistake! thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is `put_line`, not `out_line`.

Comment: @Sathya, I saw your comment only after I posted my reply.

Comment: that's fine, no worries :) huge fan of your site